# How to make border for a scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to make a border for the two sides in a scene but there is some kind of error. Here is the code I used:

```swift
let leftEdge : SKNode = SKNode()
leftEdge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointZero, toPoint: CGPointMake(0.0, self.size.height + 100))

leftEdge.position = CGPointZero;

self.addChild(leftEdge)

let rightEdge : SKNode = SKNode()
rightEdge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointZero, toPoint: CGPointMake(0.0, self.size.height + 100))
rightEdge.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width, 0.0);

self.addChild(rightEdge)
```

But the top border and bottom border get the borders and the two sides it seems like they have border outside the the scene because I shoot object toward them it goes out of the scene and gets back. The question is how do I make borders only for the two sides, the left and the right?

Comment: Set `scaleMode = .ResizeFill` and use `view.frame.size` instead of `self.size`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 1
    self.physicsBody = border
```

obviously you can add your own physics to your border.